# display percentage data mysql into textview android studio

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql

i want to display a percentage data from database mysql into text view in android studio. my rest API use php language. but the code to display the data is still wrong. what i should do?

Comment: This question gives to little detail to be able to answer this properly, although it is probably just put here so you can answer it yourself.

Comment: *what should I do* You should start with reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then provide the code, some sample data, the expected results and the actual results.

Comment: the code in comment

Answer (score 0):

code in java

```
public void getPersentase(){
        class GetPersentase extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                showPersentase(s);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
                return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(konfigurasi.URL_PERSEN_SANGAT_PUAS_PERDATA,params);
            }
        }
        new GetPersentase().execute();
    }

    public void showPersentase(String json){
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(konfigurasi.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
            sangatpuasperdata.setText(c.getString(konfigurasi.URL_PERSEN_SANGAT_PUAS_PERDATA));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```